# App Crashes When Observing Real Time Chat Data with Firebase-iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am currently learning `Swift` and I decided to make an `iOS` messaging app using `Firebase`. I am using `JSQMessageViewController` as my chat template and everything is working fine except for the fact that the app crashes when two users talking to each other are in the chat room at the same time. I am getting this error near the bottom of the function below: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

Here is my code for observing and retrieving message data. I call this everytime the view appears:

```
private func observeMessages() {
    messageRef = ref.child("ChatRooms").child(chatRoomId!).child("Messages")

    let messageQuery = messageRef.queryLimited(toLast:25)

    newMessageRefHandle = messageQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let messageData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>


        if  let data        = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject],
            let id          = data["sender_id"] as? String,
            let name        = data["name"] as? String,
            let text        = data["text"] as? String,
            let time        = data["time"] as? TimeInterval,
            !text.isEmpty
        {
            if id != uid! {
                let updateRead  = ref.child("ChatRooms").child(self.chatRoomId!).child("Messages").child(snapshot.key)
                updateRead.updateChildValues(["status":"read"])
            }
            if let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, senderDisplayName: name, date: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: time), text: text)
            {
                self.messages.append(message)

                self.finishReceivingMessage()
            }

        }else if let id = messageData["senderId"] as! String!,
            let photoURL = messageData["photoURL"] as! String! { // 1

            if let mediaItem = JSQPhotoMediaItem(maskAsOutgoing: id == self.senderId) {

                self.addPhotoMessage(withId: id, key: snapshot.key, mediaItem: mediaItem)

                if photoURL.hasPrefix("gs://") {
                    self.fetchImageDataAtURL(photoURL, forMediaItem: mediaItem, clearsPhotoMessageMapOnSuccessForKey: nil)
                }
            }
        }else {
            print("Error! Could not decode message data")
        }
    })
    updatedMessageRefHandle = messageRef.observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
        let key = snapshot.key

        //I am getting an error on this line 
        let messageData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String> 

        if let photoURL = messageData["photoURL"] as String! { 
            // The photo has been updated.
            if let mediaItem = self.photoMessageMap[key] { 
                self.fetchImageDataAtURL(photoURL, forMediaItem: mediaItem, clearsPhotoMessageMapOnSuccessForKey: key)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Curious to what I might be doing wrong here. All help is appreciated!

Comment: What's the error? Please [edit] your question to include the error.

Comment: BTW - code such as `as String!` or `as! String!` is not correct. If anything use `as! String`. Better yet, don't do any forced-casting unless you can guarantee it can't fail.

Comment: @rmaddy ok I have added the error message and commented on the line it appears in the code.

Comment: Either `snapshot.value` is `nil` or it's not a dictionary. This is why you shouldn't be using `as!`. Use `if let` and `as?`.

Comment: @rmaddy Ok, everything works perfectly fine though as long as both users aren't on the chat screen at the same time. That is the only time it crashes. Why would that be?

Comment: You need to first determine the cause of the crash. Is it `nil` or something other than a dictionary? Then figure out why is not a non-nil dictionary. Use the debugger.

Comment: @rmaddy I believe it is `nil`.